# CachedNetworkImage is not displaying image though image is not null

Tags: flutter, caching, networkimageview

I am facing this weird error, though `imageUrl` is `not null`, `placeholder` is getting triggered instead of `image build`.

```
 Container(
          height: specialOfferTileHeight,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          ),
          child: CachedNetworkImage(
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              imageUrl: homeSpecialModel.image.url,
              placeholder: (context, url) => Text(url),
              errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Text(error)),
        )
```

Output:

[image]

imageUrl is [url](https://res.cloudinary.com/dpurb6xes/image/upload/v1668425797/vivans/ijynvhpdy7hms8z2vuhh.png)

Comment: Please share specialOfferTileHeight value and the output you're getting and the output you desire

Comment: `SpecialOfferTileHeight` = 16 * 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restart it started working as expected !

Answer (score 0):

It took me about 25s to load the image for the first time. And for flutter, it may take more than 25s, you can try with a lighter image to try

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you are specifying correct url. Try to debug with `print(homeSpecialModel.image.url);`. Check that it is exact url that you provided. Or you can directly put String value of url like

`imageUrl: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dpurb6xes/image/upload/v1668425797/vivans/ijynvhpdy7hms8z2vuhh.png",`

If the url is correct, but still you are getting this error then provide with screenshots please.

Comment: In reply to your answer, i have returned url as a placeholder, so it is ought to be same. And screenshot, is already produced in the output section . Please find the same in my question.